# What is the equivalent in SystemC to verilog wire?

Tags: signals, verilog, systemc

I'm converting some verilog code to SC. Here is a case made me confused:
In verilog, a continuous assignment such as:

```
wire a;
assign a =1;
```

Where a will get 1 immediately after the assignment. If we write it in SC:

```
sc_signal<bool> a;
a.write(1);
```

The current value of a will not be 1. How to resolve this problem? Like the following?

```
bool a;
a = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

In Verilog, you are not guaranteed to read the updated value of a continuous assignment if you are changing the RHS and reading the LHS in two different processes synchronized to the same time. You need to use a non-blocking assignment to avoid a race condition.

In SystemC, the `write()` method is similar to a non-blocking assignment. The difference is that you are required to use the `write()` method in SystemC. So .you should only be writing to signals as the output of a thread/process. If you need to read the signal within the process, then you need to use a variable local to the thread.

Comment: You are right, I think. Thx. I found SC is harder than verilog, though I'm familar with C++.

Comment: They are different languages with different strengths and weaknesses. Trying to convert line-by-line is what is difficult. BTW, please accept this answer by marking it.